# Is there an existing term for the percentage of values that fall within some threshold of the maximum value in a time series?

Tags: time-series, distributions

I have a time series where I would like find the peak value in the series and then determine what percentage of other values fall within some threshold of that maximum value.  Mathematically trivial to calculate.  But it had me wondering whether or not there was an existing term for this.

Comment: Do you mean calculating percentage of values equal to mode (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mode_%28statistics%29) ?

Comment: @Tim A peak (high value) need not be a mode (value with highest frequency) or vice versa.

Comment: @NickCox agree, but I try to understand what OP means by flat-topness

Comment: The time series aspect and distribution aspect are in principle separate. If a series was very often at or near its peaks, it would lend to be left skewed, etc. but left-skewness need not imply that the highest values are especially common.

Comment: Thanks for the responses.  I edited the question to avoid some confusion hopefully.

Comment: I am not aware of an existing term. If that's generally true, then good news: you get to make up the name.